# Split words in file with spaces

Tags: c#, string, split, streamreader

I'm reading in a file, which has 4 words per line. I want to grab each word and put into a string array. I thought the space between each word was a tab so I tried using the Split method to split the line whenever it sees a tab. But the space between the words is more than a tab, how do I tell the split method to do it this way?

Relevant part of code:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
    string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var words = line.Split(new Char[] {'\t'}); //Does not work..

    return words;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `Split` by space and remove empty entries with using  `StringSplitOptions`

```
var words = line.Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: It worked :) Don't know why your answer was downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Add 'StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries' to the Split parameter list

```
               {
                    string line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    var words = line.Split(new Char[] {'\t'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    return words;
                }
```

If there are other characters between your numbers, not just the \t, then in you can specify more than one split character in the split list.

```
var words = line.Split(new Char[] {'\t', ' ','_'.......}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you don't have idea about number of spaces then you have find someother way like, split with space and then remove spaces from strings

```
var words = line.Split(' ');
for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
   words[i].Replace(" ",string.empty);

Or

var words = line.Split.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```